# Using jquery versions 1.6 and above makes Django's FilteredSelectMutliple unusable

Tags: jquery, django, forms, jquery-validation-engine

I'm doing a Django project that needs me to use FilteredSelectMultiple and this is an example of how it looks like:

```
crews = ModelMultipleChoiceField(
          queryset=Crew.objects.all(),
          widget=widgets.FilteredSelectMultiple(
            "Crews", is_stacked=False ),
          required=True
        )
```

Of course, at the template, I have properly called SelectBox, SelectFilter and core.js:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="/web/js/core.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="/web/js/SelectFilter2.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="/web/js/SelectBox.js" ></script>
```

This works for every jquery versions below 1.6. Now the problem is, I actually need a jquery version 1.6 and higher. Reason is, I need to use the updated validationEngine. Why, it's because whenever I validate a form using validationEngine, it actually goes beyond the form and I want it to stay into the div of that form.

To prevent it from happening, I need to add some options whenever I declare the validationEngine and this is how I do it:

```
$("#addform").validationEngine({
  relative: true,
  overflownDIV: ".data_container",
});
```

The newer version of validationEngine requires me to have at least 1.6 and above versions of jQuery.

The options I have tried/thought so far to solve this are:

1. Find a stable jQuery version that can load both properly

   - I failed at this. I tried to use all jQuery versions between 1.4.2 and up to the latest, which is 1.7.1, but had no luck
2. Load 2 jQuery versions

   - This sounds good, but I tried and still failed
3. Change validationEngine into something else

   - This is the last choice that I really don't want to take. We've already done so much that using another might require us time that's beyond what we have.

Now, my real question is, are there any solutions besides the options that I have thought so far? There are no updated js files for rendering the FilteredSelectMultiple widget yet.

Comment: Are you doing this in the Django admin or are you attempting to use the admin's FilteredSelectMultiple widget in your own form outside the admin?

Comment: Hi, yes, I'm using FilteredSelectMultiple widget in my own form outside of the admin.

Answer (score 0):

Django is currently shipping with jQuery 1.4.2. Even trunk is still using that version. So all the widgets and such are built with that version in mind. Most likely there's been some backwards-incompatible change in jQuery 1.6+.

That means you essentially have two choices.

1. You can load two versions of jQuery (1.4.2 and 1.6+) and put one in noConflict mode.
2. Don't use the the Django widget and find something else to satisfy the purpose (outside of Django) that is 1.6+ compatible.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll try to do the first option for the mean time. But I think we'll end up doing the second option.

Comment: [Not sure, but this commit might easily give it away, what to fix/override](https://github.com/django/django/commit/8bbca211b6d4457e2f7acc3d41e54373f03ecddd). Though upgradeing to Djang1.6 is surely a be better option than this...